# Перевод из десятичной СС в двоичную

Tags: c++, алгоритм, системы-счисления

Добрый день, есть такой код, переводящий число из 10-й системы в 2-ю.

```
int x, c;
while (c > 0)
{
   std::cout << bool(x&c);
   c >>= 1;
}
```

Допустим, возьмем x = 5, c = 4(как я понял нужно брать такое число, которое в двоичной даст столько же битов сколько в x). 
Теперь перейду к bool(x&c)(пик).
После расчетов получаем `bool = 1, bool = 0, bool = 1; 101 - 5`.
Как работает этот перевод?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сравнивается единица в n-ном разряде и значение n-ного разряда числа, результат сравнения выводится.

Comment: Примечание: в коде ошибка — при отрицательном значении переменной `c` число не будет переведено и распечатано. Для исправления надо заменить все `int` на `unsigned`.

Comment: @Arhad `x` задается с клавиатуры, а `c` я циклом увеличиваю до количества разрядов `x`.
@ВладимирМартьянов я это понимаю. Как в итоге результат сравнения приводит к получению числа `5`?

Comment: @Dippa За одну итерацию цикла выводится один бит. Если понимаемую вами операцию сравнения провести n раз, будет выведено n бит.

Comment: `Как в итоге результат сравнения приводит к получению числа 5` — число `c` взято таким образом, что оно 1) содержит в себе единичный бит; 2) этот бит находится в той же позиции, что и старший значащий бит числа `x`. Дальше мы побитовым сдвигом прогоняем этот единичный бит слева направо, рассматривая его с помощью операции `&` как битовую маску для проверки нужного двоичного разряда числа `x`.

Comment: *@Arhad понимаю все до момента `битовую маску для проверки нужного двоичного разряда числа x.`
Вот я получил `bool(x&c) = 1` в первой итерации, что я получил _по факту_, что значит вот эта единица, и какое значение она имеет в числе `5`. Прощу прощения, если я (очень) некорректно задаю вопрос.*
UPD. Я все понял, большое спасибо.

Comment: По факту `bool(x&c) = 1` при первом вызове означает, что третий бит числа `5` равен единице. При втором вызове `bool(x&c) = 0` означает, что второй бит числа `5` равен нулю (мы же сдвинули `c0 == 4 == 0b100` на один разряд вправо (`>>`), так что `c1 == 0b010 == 2`). При третьем вызове `bool(x&c) = 1` означает, что первый бит числа `5` равен нулю (мы опять сдвинули `c1 == 2 == 0b010` на один разряд вправо , так что `c2 == 0b001 == 1`)

Comment: bool(n)  в любом случаи  принимат значение либо 0(false) ,   либо    1(true) если n  не равен нулю: и с чего вы взяли что этот код переводит число в двоичный вид

Answer (score 1):

возьмем некоторое число, например `c = 12`, оно имеет двоичный вид  `1100` и перед 
 ними еще `28` нулей в четырехбайтовых числах (индексация справа налево), и если бы вы указали, что `x` имеет значение `1`, тогда ваш код был бы правильным, если не учесть, что увидим зеркальное отражение, а именно `0011`

```
int x = 1, c = 12;
while (c > 0)
{
   std::cout << bool(x&c);
   c >>= 1;
}

1100 & 1 это 0  // (c & x) с >= 1
0110 & 1 это 0   //  c  >>= 1
0011 & 1 это 1   // c >>= 1  
0001 & 1 это 1 // если сдвинем еще направо, то получим с == 0, и цикл прекратится
```